# C# JQuery.Now equivalent

Tags: c#, jquery, json, datetime, time

What's the equivalent to jQuery.now in C#? jQuery.now returns a value such as "1472654236737".

I've tried DateTime.now but I'm not sure what the format is.

Comment: `$.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since the Jan 1st 1970 epoch. See the question I marked as duplicate for how to do that in C#

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .NET 4.6 then

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

is what you are looking for